# curl is not working on Windows but working on Mac OSX

Tags: tensorflow, curl, tensorflow-serving

I'm new in tensorflow and window

I send curl to my tensorflow server on Linux and it was worked on OSX.

```sh
curl -d '{"instances":[{"image":{"b64":"'"$(base64 ./test_input.png)"'"}}]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/ocr:predict
```

returns

```sh
{
    "predictions": [[44032, 44172]
    ]
}%
```

But `curl` is not working on Windows 10 and I don't know why

This is error message

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 19
{ "error": "JSON Parse error: Invalid value. at offset: 0" }
```

Comment: Did you compare the curl versions you are using?

Comment: mac curl version is `curl 7.65.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) libcurl/7.65.2 OpenSSL/1.1.1c zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.2`
and windows curl version is `curl 7.55.1 (Windows) 
libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL`
@a_horse_with_no_name Is it a version problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add escape character for the **nested double quotation** as below? Windows and Macos is pretty different.

```
curl -d '{"instances":[{"image":{"b64":"'\"$(base64 ./test_input.png)\"'"}}]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/ocr:predict
```

Comment: thankyou! @donglinjy but your comment works! but there's another error. 
```shell
{"error":"JSON Parse error: Invalid value. at offset: 0"}
```
Do you know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to use different quotation marks for Windows. Try

```
curl -d "{\"instances\": ...}" -X POST ...
```